# NoSql vs BigTable (comparison of client API's)

Tags: nosql, bigtable

This might sound like a dumb question but I am recently learning about a Big Table.

Would someone please tell me the advantage of using Big Table over NoSql databases. I eventually see both of them as semi-structured data storage. Some people mention that Big Table has much more simple interface as compared to a NoSql database but I don't quite understand how. Also is there a way I can try out API's of Big Table ??

Also , does Big Table have web interfaces , if yes can I get links to it as well ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BigTable is Google's system to store large documents of data. It doesn't generates relations between documents as it doesn't benefit the architecture of Google's applications. This philosophy of "Unrelated" data-instances are the basic idea of [NoSQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL). So long story short, BigTable is NoSQL as NoSQl is the theoretical idea ( just like RDBMS is the basic theory of MySQL,MSSQL and others ).

An approach of bigtable has been made and gave birth to [hadoop](http://hadoop.apache.org/). It is widely used by many industries.An other related implementation is [storm](http://storm-project.net/) which tries to operates faster when it comes to serve real time data.

Regarding [NoSQL databases](http://nosql-database.org/) you should take a good look at [hbase](http://hbase.apache.org/), [cassandra](http://cassandra.apache.org/) and if you are coming from the RDBMS world [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/) would be the best choice to start realizing the use of NoSQL.

Mind to take a good look at the Google's notes regarding [BigTable](http://research.google.com/archive/bigtable.html).

Cheers!